# Write a Custom directive for States in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a custom directive that will simply display a list of states. However I would like to build a directive which is as general as possible for lists that has objects that contain item_name and item_value. So for instance, i can use the same directive to populate cities, zipcodes, etc.

Here is what i have so far:

My template looks like this (not sure i need to iterate inside it)
    
        {{defaultname}}

My directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('locselect', function () {
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

};
var select = {
    replace:true,
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/search-filters/prp-select.html',
    scope: {
       defaultname: "defaulValue", 
        items:"="
    }
}    
return select;
});
```

And my implementation of the directive in the html looks like this:

```
  <locselect items="states" default-value="State"></locselect>
```

Assume a scope of a controller that populates states or any other list inside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add ng-model also to your directive to bind the selected value to controller scope.

This might be what your are looking at:

```
 app.directive('locselect', function () {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.ngModel = scope.defaultItem;
        console.log(scope.items);
    }

    var select = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'prp-select.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            items: "="
        }
    }

    return select;
});
```

and your directive's template (app/search-filters/prp-select.html) should be

```
<select ng-options="item as item.full_name for item in items">
    <option value="">Select State...</option>
</select>
```

and this is how you would want to use -

```
<locselect ng-model="modSelectedState" items="states"></locselect>
```

Check the [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XhbwhIBmmuKbkqFlWyRM?p=preview)

Comment: I tried your approach but it doesn't work. Here is a link to plunkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTaRPoAsQQQ6OSEQLS3a?p=info).

Comment: that's because your object has different keys instead of item_name and item_value. I've modified the post as well a plunkr. Please check

Comment: I've also removed the need of default-value as it can be handled directly by the ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic directive which prints a list of values:

```
app.directive('list', function () {
  return {
    scope : {
      listItems : "="
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in listItems">{{item.name}}, {{item.value}}</li></ul>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HHzDoYrqln0pawuL7MuU?p=preview

**Edit**

exmaple based on your plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SnpO2admMHmJV25lyi4p?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to implement it using <select> since the whole design of this is based on 'select'. Anyway I uploaded my code to plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/mTaRPoAsQQQ6OSEQLS3a?p=info if you wish to take a look.

Comment: @DavidBarel i made second directive to work http://plnkr.co/edit/SnpO2admMHmJV25lyi4p?p=preview

Comment: @MajobB thanks for the solution. The only thing that is missing is the default-value. Right now it is hard coded in the html file like so: <option value="">Select State...</option>, whereas the ideal solution, for generalization purposes would be something like: <option value="">{{defaultItem}}</option>. Whereby the defaultItem is defined in the scope.

Comment: @DavidBarel new version with default value: http://plnkr.co/edit/H70n3TnbNfeY4Yfaas3g?p=preview